# How to execute a function when flutter scheduled local notification received?

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

I was trying to create an app that schedules a todo and send a notification. For notification, I am using flutter_local_notifications package. Now i want to show an overlay when a notification is received. For overlay, i was trying to use  flutter_overlay_window package. I tried to call flutter overlay window from onDidReceiveLocalNotification method. But it looks like this method never calls when a notification is received. Please Can anyone help me to archive this?

here is the code that I'm using

```dart
final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
  final DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsDarwin = DarwinInitializationSettings(
    onDidReceiveLocalNotification: (id, title, body, payload) {
      FlutterOverlayWindow.showOverlay(height: 200,width: 200,overlayTitle: 'hello');
    },
  );
  const LinuxInitializationSettings initializationSettingsLinux = LinuxInitializationSettings(defaultActionName: 'Open notification');
  final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
      InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsDarwin, macOS: initializationSettingsDarwin, linux: initializationSettingsLinux);
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
    initializationSettings,
    onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (details) {

    },
```